# in the reality or in reality

Tags: grammar

Should I use definite article with "reality"? Does it depend on the context?
For example:

> The campaign should show that there is a small number of crimes that
>   actually take place every day, and it should show that serious crimes
>   rarely happen **in the reality**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can’t use an article with “reality” as you have used that word in your example.

The reason for this is that in this context “reality” means the abstract idea of “the sum of all the real things in the universe” and so we don’t give it an article (it’s implied but not used). Other abstract ideas don’t take articles like “terrorism” and “breakfast” (as in, “Can we meet for breakfast?”). 
Compare the difference between these sentences:

> I met him in high school. (I met him while we were in the abstract idea of the stage of life when we were attending high school.)
>
> I met him in **the** high school. (I met him in a building that is a high school.)

**However**, be aware that “reality” has other meanings in other contexts and can then take an article. For example, it can mean a particular real event or set of facts, as in:

> His childhood dream of living beside the beach only became **a reality** when his parents passed away.
>
> **The reality** of colonial Australia’s Black Wars is brutally depicted in “The Nightingale”.

Comment: What about the phrase: (The) reality is that... (she doesn't love you). Do we need THE or not?